# Replacing HTML element based on the classname?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

I have been tasked to replace the phone numbers with an anchor tag with a link and text to the demo page of our website.  We use white-label software which does not give me access to simply change the text as it's linked to a back-end panel where you change the phone number there but you can't change it to anything else.

The snippet of code the phone number sits in is the following:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p class="h6 margin-top-sm margin-bottom-sm text-center-xs">
            <i class="fa fa-phone margin-right-xs"></i>
            <strong class="hidden-xs">Call us now:</strong>
            <a class="text-info" href="tel:IRL +353 0000000 UK +44 00000000"><strong>IRL +353 00000000 UK +44 00000000</strong></a>
            <span class="margin-left-sm margin-right-sm text-gray-dark">|</span>
            <i class="fa fa-commenting-o margin-right-xs"></i>
            <a href="/contact-us" class="text-black"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
            <span class="margin-left-sm margin-right-sm text-gray-dark header-vertical-line">|</span>
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o margin-right-xs"></i>
            <a href="/faq" class="text-black">
                <strong class="hidden-xs">Check our FAQ</strong>
                <strong class="visible-xs-inline">FAQ</strong>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to keep the links to the FAQ & the Contact Page but get rid of this:

```
<strong class="hidden-xs">Call us now:</strong>
<a class="text-info" href="tel:IRL +353 0000000 UK +44 00000000"><strong>IRL +353 00000000 UK +44 00000000</strong></a>
```

and replace it with:

```
<a href="/demo">Book A Demo</a>
```

without changing anything else or disturbing anything else on the webpage.

I was trying to use `innerHTML.replace()` to try it but it wasn't working.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

My attempt:

```
$(".col-xs-12").each(function(){ 
    $("strong", this).each(function(i,obj){ 
        if (i===0) { 
            $(this).html(""); 
        } else if(i === 1) { 
            var newHtml = '<a href="safetyfreelancer.com/demo">Book A Demo</a>'; 
            $(this).html(newHtml); 
         } 
     });
 });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `
<script>
    $(".col-xs-12").each(function(){
        $("strong", this).each(function(i,obj){
            if (i===0) {
                $(this).html("");
            }
            else if(i === 1) {
                var newHtml = '<a href="https://safetyfreelancer.com/demo">Book A Demo</a>';
                $(this).html(newHtml);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
`

Tried the above but it's affecting other elements

I also tried using `.innerHTML.replace` but it's not working either

Comment: I have to trouble you to put this in the question, it will be readable and easier to copy while answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, in this case, is using `jQuery` selectors and using them alongside anchor tags. You can find more about them [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

When selecting the anchor tags, use `$('a[href^="tel"]')`, this will select all the anchor tags that have a href that starts with `tel`. This way, you will only select those that contain a phone number. Then you can manipulate it whichever way.

```
$('a[href^="tel"]').each(function(index, anchor) {
  $(anchor).prev('strong.hidden-xs').remove();
  $(anchor).html('book a demo');
  $(anchor).prop('href', '/demo');
});
```

Comment: Good answer. I've taken the liberty of also adding the removal of the `<strong>` tag, like in the question. This approach modifies the original `<a>` tag, which means that attributes such as the class (`text-info`) and event handlers (if any) are kept. If you ( @IAmAndy ) don't want that, you can also do `$(anchor).replaceWith('<a href="/demo">...</a>')` rather than `.html()` and `.prop()`. This makes a whole new tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) of the parentNode to replace the anchor and also [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to remove the `Call us now` text.

```js
function replaceCallUs() {
  const callUsElm = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='tel']")[0];

  // Remove the `Call us now` text
  let callUsText = callUsElm.previousSibling;
  // // find the text element
  while(callUsText && callUsText.nodeType !== 1) {
    callUsText = callUsText.previousSibling;
}
 callUsText && callUsElm.parentNode.removeChild(callUsText);
 
  // Replace the call us anchor this the demo link
  var myLink = document.createElement("a");
  myLink.innerHTML = "Book A Demo";
  myLink.setAttribute('href', '/demo');
  
  callUsElm.parentNode.replaceChild(myLink, callUsElm);  

}

replaceCallUs();
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p class="h6 margin-top-sm margin-bottom-sm text-center-xs">
            <i class="fa fa-phone margin-right-xs"></i>
            <strong class="hidden-xs">Call us now:</strong>
            <a class="text-info" href="tel:IRL +353 0000000 UK +44 00000000"><strong>IRL +353 00000000 UK +44 00000000</strong></a>
            <span class="margin-left-sm margin-right-sm text-gray-dark">|</span>
            <i class="fa fa-commenting-o margin-right-xs"></i>
            <a href="/contact-us" class="text-black"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
            <span class="margin-left-sm margin-right-sm text-gray-dark header-vertical-line">|</span>
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle-o margin-right-xs"></i>
            <a href="/faq" class="text-black">
                <strong class="hidden-xs">Check our FAQ</strong>
                <strong class="visible-xs-inline">FAQ</strong>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```